# Java - Sending Email without JavaMail - EHLO Client/Server Responses

Tags: java, sockets, email, smtp, client-server

I have been searching online and doing testing for the better of 6 hour straight, and I cannot get this to work. I'd like to use JavaMail, however my professor wanted us to work with sockets... I am just trying to send an email with java to a Gmail account.

Anyway, I started using EHLO rather than HELO for sending a message to the server as it is "newer" from what i've read. However, I find myself stuck. At the midway point of my code you will notice that it is all commented out until I close the socket. This is as far as I can get good replies from the server.

Let me just show you my code here:

```
public class MailComponent{

final static String MAIL_SERVER = "smtp.gmail.com";
final static int SMTP_PORT = 25;
Socket socket = null;

public MailComponent(){
    // Making Constructor Later
}

public void sendMail() throws Exception{

    try{
        // Establish TCP Connection With Mail Server
        socket = new Socket(MAIL_SERVER, SMTP_PORT);

        // Create a Buffered Reader to read one line at a time
        InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(inReader);

        // Read Server's Greeting
        String serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        if (!serverResponse.startsWith("220")){
            throw new Exception("220 Reply Not Received From Server!");
        }
        System.out.println(serverResponse);

        // Reference socket's output stream
        OutputStream oStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        // Send EHLO command
        String heloCommand = "EHLO smtp.gmail.com\r\n";
        oStream.write(heloCommand.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        if (!serverResponse.startsWith("250"))
            throw new Exception("250 Reply Not Received From Server!");
        System.out.println(serverResponse);

        // Get Responses...
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server Response: " + serverResponse);
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server Response: " + serverResponse);
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server Response: " + serverResponse);
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server Response: " + serverResponse);
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server Response: " + serverResponse);
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server Response: " + serverResponse);
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Final Response: " + serverResponse);
        // END EHLO Responses

        // Send TLS command
        String tlsCommand = ("STARTTLS" + "\r\n");
        oStream.write(tlsCommand.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("STARTTLS Response: " + serverResponse);



        /* Commented out

        //Send the MAIL FROM command
        String fromCommand = ("MAIL FROM: <example@gmail.com>\r\n");
        oStream.write(fromCommand.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Mail From Reponse: " + serverResponse);

        // Send RCPT TO command
        String toCommand = ("RCPT TO: <example@gmail.com>\r\n");
        oStream.write(toCommand.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        //serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        //System.out.println("RCPT To Response: " + serverResponse);

        // Send DATA command
        String dataCommand = ("DATA\r\n");
        oStream.write(dataCommand.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Data Response: "+ serverResponse);

        // Subject 
        String subCommand = ("SUBJECT: Email Test\r\n");
        oStream.write(subCommand.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        String msg = ("Some random Message");
        oStream.write(msg.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

        // End Message data
        String endMsg = ("\r\n.\r\n");
        oStream.write(endMsg.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("End Data Command: "+ serverResponse);

        // Send QUIT message
        String quitMsg = ("QUIT\r\n");
        oStream.write(quitMsg.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        serverResponse = bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Quit Command: "+ serverResponse);


        End comment*/



        if (socket != null){
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("Closed Socket Connection!");
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){System.err.println(ioe);}
}
```

}

Notice the "Final Response" in my output has no hyphen between the 250 and SMTPUTF8. That's how I know its the last response before I have to say something back. Once I send the STARTTLS command, I have absolutely no idea what to do.

[image: Output From Running Above Code]

I would really appreciate some help as to what i'm supposed to put after the STARTTLS command (the last command before all my comments). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply put: when you issue the `STARTTLS` command, you're telling the remote server: _"ok, I want to exchange encription keys, and encript all subsequent traffic using those keys"_. So the server expects you to do exactly that: share your keys and encript all further communication. But you keep sending plain text commands, so the server doesn't understand you. **So**: since I highly doubt that your professor wants you to do TLS authentication by hand using sockets, I'd **just drop the STARTTLS command**. I don't know if Gmail accepts non-encripted communication, but give it a try.

Comment: Don't start with gmail. They are very picky. Instead set up a Linux box or talk to exchange, both on port 25.

Comment: @Walen you are forced to start the TLS command to continue. Should I try sending to a yahoo mail or AOL? I have no idea what Linux box or exchange is..

Comment: Yes, try with a less-secure mail server (Yahoo might work, dunno), or ask your professor if something like this [FakeSMTP local server](https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/) would be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

don't send "STARTTLS" your code is okkk